# Binding parameters by PDO not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I've got this code:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$jsonvprencode = json_encode($jsonvpr);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `wp_posts` SET  `post_content` = :val WHERE `ID` = $idvpr");
$stmt->bind_param(":val", $jsonvprencode);
$stmt->execute();
```

When trying to execute it it returns `Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /var/www/html/crawlnew.php on line 432`

I can't understand what is going on here -_-

Comment: I'm guessing the prepare failed

Comment: You are using mysqli and you used named placeholder. Can't do.

Comment: I supose, but I don't understand why. Replacing the parameter with a string, and ID with a number, the query works right. Variables $jsonvprencode and $idvpr are valid strings as well :S

Comment: you are mixing mysqli and PDO.

Comment: If I remember correctly mysqli only support `?` as placeholder. If you want to use `:val` as a placeholder. It is pretty much like @niyou told you.

Comment: And why dont you bind the value of ID too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MySQLi with PreparedStatements**

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `wp_posts` SET  `post_content` = ? WHERE `ID` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("si", $jsonvprencode,$idvpr);
```

**PDO with Prepared Statements**

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `wp_posts` SET  `post_content` = :jsonvprencode WHERE `ID` = :idvpr");

$stmt->bindParam(':jsonvprencode', $jsonvprencode);

$stmt->bindParam(':idvpr', $idvpr);
```

Comment: This give me another error -_- `Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in /var/www/html/crawlnew.php on line 435`

Comment: imo this is maybe correct for mysqli...but he is asking about PDO.

Comment: @CornezuelodelCenteno see edits now ... there are 2 ways to bind parameters ... with MySQLi/PS and PDO/PS

Answer (score 0):

You have to open a PDO connection

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
```

and then use this object

Comment: instead of my $conn one?

Comment: your solution gives me `Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_param() in /var/www/html/crawlnew.php on line 432`

Comment: I was using your method before, and the error was diferent, but still were errors, check my answer!

Comment: exactly - the method is bindParam

Comment: btw - you should aesily read the documentation at php.net: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an error in your statement.

```
printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
```

try to echo the error if you have one. If you have an error in your statement you didn't get an proper object.

Comment: Using `printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);` (I was suposed to change $mysqli for my connection variable, right?) don't returns any sql error :S